# Why are my inline style(s) getting removed from my vue.js application?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I am using a [Talwinid UI calendar](https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/data-display/calendars) component within my vuejs application.

I am having trouble with this line:

```
<div class="col-start-1 col-end-2 row-start-1 grid divide-y divide-gray-100" style="grid-template-rows: repeat(48, minmax(3.5rem, 1fr))">
...
```

When my application compiles, the inline style:

```
style="grid-template-rows: repeat(48, minmax(3.5rem, 1fr))"
```

...is getting removed.

[Here is a Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/1qKjFQm4ex) of what I am seeing. In this example. I have removed the inline style attribute. As you will see, the hours of the day are all squished together. I am trying to get them (and the events) to spread out like they do in the demo.

Using dev-tools, I am able to copy/paste the inline style(s) and the elements look much better. I've looked through my `.eslintrc.js` file for anything flagging inline styles, but don't see anything. Same with my `.prettierrc` file.

How can I allow the inline style attribute to remain in my compiled code?

Comment: if the tailwind classes are removed, does the style stay?

Comment: @Damzaky Unfortunately no. If I remove the class attribute (or just the classes) the layout really falls apart. The `style` attribue is still missing as well.

Comment: Does it happen with any inlined style in your application? Is the style tag removed or replaced by something else? Could you try to make an online reproduction of the problem (with a real Vuejs setup, the tailwind play doesn't reproduce the problem).

Comment: A possible solution is to simply put your inline style into a css class (not a tailwind one), and apply the class.

Comment: I am able to set `style="background-color: red"` to an element and it seems to work fine. Everything is red! I'll try moving the other inline style to a separate class.

Comment: Moving the inline style into it's own class in my `<style>` block _seems_ to have an effect. I will continue to tweak things and update my question as I go. Thank you very much. I really appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

#### Debugging downwards

As you progressively remove other parts of your code, at what stage does that CSS style no longer vanish during processing?

#### Debugging upwards

Start from a blank page and add only that. Does it get deleted during processing?

If so, it is a Tailwind bug.

If not, at some stage of working upwards or downwards, you will find the culprit.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an anwser, as it doesn't provide any solution to OP's problem, but rather tips about how to find the problem.
Some people might not open the question seeing there is already a pending anwser.